# How to check if array with keys and values is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays that get populated when a form is submitted.

```
$groceries = array(
    "Veggies" => array( 
        "Cabbage, ear(s)" => $_POST['cabbageQTY'],
        "Carrots, bag(s)" => $_POST['carrotQTY'],
        "Tomatoes, vine(s)" => $_POST['tomatoeQTY']
    ),
    "Meats" => array( 
        "Ground Beef, lb(s)" => $_POST['groundBeefQTY'],
        "Steak, lb(s)" => $_POST['steakQTY'],
        "Pork, lb(s)" => $_POST['porkQTY']
    ),
    "Desserts" => array(
        "Ice Cream, gallon(s)" => $_POST['iceCreamQTY'],
        "Jello, box(es)" => $_POST['jelloQTY'],
        "Pie, box(es)" => $_POST['pieQTY']
    )
);
```

If all the fields come up null, is there a way to check to see if the values will be empty?

I read somewhere else you can try and do this.

```
!array_filter($groceries)
```

But I think this would work for a 1 dimentional array. 
Anyway to do this in a 2d array? If you guys could tell me how to do this, it would be awesome

Thank you in advance.

Comment: combine array_walk() with array_filter()

Comment: perhaps look into count() as well to count the content in the array. Example if( count($groceries) > 0 ) {echo "My groceries array has something!";}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can use `<input type="text" name="cabbageQTY" required>` . Then user cannot leave them blank. After if its not work for you you can try to lookup all posts at the same time if they are null or not.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
  if  $value==(null) echo $key.' value is null';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the question is explained fully. If this is only being populated from a form POST, then there is no NULL, they should exist as empty strings. If you want to save an empty string text like "Empty", then maybe do something like this:

```
$blank = "Empty";
...
"Ground Beef, lb(s)" => $_POST['groundBeefQTY'] == "" ? $blank : $_POST['groundBeefQTY'],
...
```